# Empty Decrypted Text Issue in Python AES Encryption/Decryption

Tags: python, encryption, aes, key-generator

I am currently working on a Python script for AES encryption and decryption using the Crypto library. The encryption part seems to be working fine, but when I try to decrypt the text, the result is an empty string. I've reviewed my code, but I can't identify the issue. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me debug and resolve this problem.

```
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode


class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key=None):
        # Initialize the AESCipher object with a key, defaulting to a randomly generated key
        self.block_size = AES.block_size
        if key:
            self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()
        else:
            self.key = Random.new().read(self.block_size)

    def encrypt(self, plain_text):
        # Encrypt the provided plaintext using AES in CBC mode
        plain_text = self.__pad(plain_text)
        iv = Random.new().read(self.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(plain_text)
        # Combine IV and encrypted text, then base64 encode for safe representation
        return b64encode(iv + encrypted_text).decode("utf-8")

    def decrypt(self, encrypted_text):
        # Decrypt the provided ciphertext using AES in CBC mode
        encrypted_text = b64decode(encrypted_text)
        iv = encrypted_text[:self.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        plain_text = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text[self.block_size:])
        return self.__unpad(plain_text)

    def get_key(self):
        # Get the base64 encoded representation of the key
        return b64encode(self.key).decode("utf-8")

    def __pad(self, plain_text):
        # Add PKCS7 padding to the plaintext
        number_of_bytes_to_pad = self.block_size - len(plain_text) % self.block_size
        padding_bytes = bytes([number_of_bytes_to_pad] * number_of_bytes_to_pad)
        padded_plain_text = plain_text.encode() + padding_bytes
        return padded_plain_text

    @staticmethod
    def __unpad(plain_text):
        # Remove PKCS7 padding from the plaintext
        last_byte = plain_text[-1]
        return plain_text[:-last_byte] if isinstance(last_byte, int) else plain_text


def save_to_notepad(text, key, filename):
    # Save encrypted text and key to a file
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write(f"Key: {key}\nEncrypted text: {text}")
    print(f"Text and key saved to {filename}")

def encrypt_and_save():
    # Take user input, encrypt, and save to a file
    user_input = ""
    while not user_input:
        user_input = input("Enter the plaintext: ")

    aes_cipher = AESCipher()  # Randomly generated key

    encrypted_text = aes_cipher.encrypt(user_input)
    key = aes_cipher.get_key()

    filename = input("Enter the filename (including .txt extension): ")
    save_to_notepad(encrypted_text, key, filename)


def decrypt_from_file():
    # Decrypt encrypted text from a file using a key
    filename = input("Enter the filename to decrypt (including .txt extension): ")
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        key = lines[0].split(":")[1].strip()
        encrypted_text = lines[1].split(":")[1].strip()

    aes_cipher = AESCipher(key)
    decrypted_bytes = aes_cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text)

    # Decoding only if the decrypted bytes are not empty
    decrypted_text = decrypted_bytes.decode("utf-8") if decrypted_bytes else ""
    print("Decrypted Text:", decrypted_text)


def encrypt_and_decrypt_in_command_line():
    # Encrypt and then decrypt user input in the command line
    user_input = ""
    while not user_input:
        user_input = input("Enter the plaintext: ")

    aes_cipher = AESCipher()

    encrypted_text = aes_cipher.encrypt(user_input)
    key = aes_cipher.get_key()

    print("Key:", key)
    print("Encrypted Text:", encrypted_text)

    decrypted_bytes = aes_cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text)
    decrypted_text = decrypted_bytes.decode("utf-8") if decrypted_bytes else ""
    print("Decrypted Text:", decrypted_text)


# Menu Interface
while True:
    print("\nMenu:")
    print("1. Encrypt and save to file")
    print("2. Decrypt from file")
    print("3. Encrypt and decrypt in command line")
    print("4. Exit")

    choice = input("Enter your choice (1, 2, 3, or 4): ")

    if choice == '1':
        encrypt_and_save()
    elif choice == '2':
        decrypt_from_file()
    elif choice == '3':
        encrypt_and_decrypt_in_command_line()
    elif choice == '4':
        print("Exiting the program. Goodbye!")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please enter 1, 2, 3, or 4.")
```

Comment: Your method of deriving the key for decryption bears no relation to how it's encoded and has no chance of producing the correct key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AESCipher.get_key` method encodes the key as a `base64` string.

Here is the relevant code:

```py
    def get_key(self):
        # Get the base64 encoded representation of the key
        return b64encode(self.key).decode("utf-8")
```

When you provide a key in the `AESCipher` constructor, you need to decode the key instead of computing a digest.

Your constructor should look as follows:

```py
class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key=None):
        # Initialize the AESCipher object with a key, 
        # defaulting to a randomly generated key
        self.block_size = AES.block_size
        if key:
            self.key = b64decode(key.encode())
        else:
            self.key = Random.new().read(self.block_size)
```